# Thread-safe NavigableSet with constant size-operation?

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, collections, thread-safety

I'm searching for a specific data structure that is exactly like `ConcurrentSkipListSet` but without the linear `size`-operation, which may be called quite often for larger sets.

I know about `Collections.synchronizedNavigableSet(new TreeSet())`, but the synchronized iteration:

```
synchronized (set) {
    Iterator<T> iter = set.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext())
    iter.next();
}
```

is quite slow.

So, do you know about a `NavigableSet` implementation that is exactly like `ConcurrentSkipListSet` but without the linear `size` operations, e.g in Apache Commons, Guava? Or should I iterate differently over the set?

Comment: You could also subclass `ConcurrentSkipListSet` yourself and insert just a bit of code that will cache and track the size of the set.

Comment: I already thought of that, maybe I try it, thanks. I just thought some other lib could probably provide an implementation.

Comment: On second thought, implementing that would probably not be worth it, given all the constraints good concurrency imposes. There's a good reason why they made it this way in the first place.

Comment: Can you reduce how much you need to know the size() so it doesn't matter? BTW the size can change while you are calling this method so you can only know what the size was, not what it is.

Comment: Yes, the size doesn't have to be that accurate (no need to block the entire data structure) and should only reflect the "best guess" at the calling time. So I started to override it using a <code>volatile</code> instance variable that holds the current size and let it increment when <code>add</code> returned <code>true</code> and decrease for <code>remove</code> analogous. Now I try to evaluate what I've done - if it's sensible at all.

Comment: The [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) is built for concurrency operations which require more traversals than add/remove elements and seems a better option for the data structure you in search of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good reason why they didn't implement it that way (i.e. with the counter).
It is about the semantics of multiprocessor programming.
There are many correctness models of concurrent programs, strong - called sequential consistency and relaxed - called quiescent consistency (see The Art of Multiprocessor Programming by Maurice Herlihy and Nir Shavit or [Quasi-Linearizability](http://mcg.cs.tau.ac.il/papers/opodis2010-quasi.pdf)).

The implementation with the counter fails to adhere to any of them.
If the size is updated before the actual add and remove operations, it may become negative (assume that you have remove and add on an empty set, remove updated the size first resulting in -1 size...). The same is if the size is updated afterwards.
Even the solution that increases the size before the add operation and decreases it after the remove has a serious drawback (however will not produce negative values). Consider two add operations with argument 'x' and one remove with the same argument 'x' (all with the same element). There may be a situation that the size will be set to 2 (the two add operations increased the counter), a state that never existed (the set never had a size of 2, notice that we always add the same element 'x' and the set cannot contain duplicates).

The way it is implemented (by counting the elements, with linear time complexity) will at least yield a value that existed at some point in time (more precisely it is quiescently consistent).